# sprintf leaves out double data C

Tags: c, embedded, printf

The sprintf function is not including the variables which I have included.
I have the following code:

```
    typedef struct
{
    double sensor_1;
    double sensor_2;
    double sensor_3;
    double sensor_4;
    int32_t acc_count;
}PAC1934_ResultData_t;
```

here is the struct for the power sensor.

```
PAC1934_ResultData_t power;
power = PAC1934_read_Power_accumulation();
uint8_t buf[100] = {0};
sprintf((char*)&buf, "  %010.9f W     %010.9f W     %010.9f W     %010.9f W    \n\r",
           power.sensor_1, power.sensor_2, power.sensor_3, power.sensor_4);
```

But the value of buf is always just some spaces and the W. I checked in the debugger and the values of power.sensor_1, ... are always correct and are non zero.
The power values are all of the type double.
The function PAC1934_read_Power_accumulation(); returns a element of type PAC1934_ResultData_t with values for all the elements of it.
What is going wrong?

When I am rewriting the code with an integer, the sprintf works fine.

EDIT: Simple code just trying to output a float or a double doesn't work. Only integer output works. I have tested it with

```
double test = 1.432;
printf("%f",test);
```

Comment: Code is an incomplete code snippet which is not sufficient for anyone to debug. Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code to check what is wrong. We do not see any types and values of your variables. Describing is not as good as showing.

Comment: Use `snprintf()` instead, & `snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "...", ...);`

Comment: If you are using newlib nano then floating point printf support is not included by default.  Try using %i and (and an integer argument) to see if this is the case.

Comment: I took the code in the question, add `#include <stdio.h>` and other lines to complete a program, including a `main` routine, a stub `PAC1934_read_Power_accumulation`, and a `puts((char *) buf)`. The output was as expected, showing the values I had put into the structure elements. Therefore, the posted question omits information that would cause this problem. It is incomplete, does not contain a [mre], and should be closed until fixed. Edit the post to provide a [mre], including complete code to reproduce the problem and information about the target platform, compiler version, and so on.

Comment: @KevinK,  Consider a [mcve].   Also "the values of power. .sensor_1, ... are always correct and are non zero." --> better to post sample values than only describe them.  "Value of buf is always just some spaces and the W" --> same here.  Better to also post the exact value (even better from code and not a debugger) of the string.  This data provides clues to what is, and what is not the problem.  Saves us all time.

Comment: Maybe the failure is just, that you are currently passing the first argument to sprintf wrong with your `sprintf((char*)&buf, ... `, which should actually either be `sprintf((char*)&buf[0], ...` or `sprintf((char*)buf, ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Candidate problems:

**No FP support** [@Tom V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71586326/sprintf-leaves-out-double-data-c/71587418#comment126521183_71586326)

Various compilers/linkers do not include floating point (FP) support automatically.  Code with only FP via `printf()/scanf()` gets fooled into thinking no FP support needed.  Research your compiler to force linking of FP support or maybe simple and some obvious FP code to your source code.

**Buffer overrun**

`sprintf((char*)&buf, "  %010.9f W ...` may overrun.  Is is good practice to *be prepared* for unexpected FP values and insure no overrun, not matter what.  `buf[100]` with `%010.9f` is not enough.

Alternatives: [@SparKot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71586326/sprintf-leaves-out-double-data-c/71587418#comment126520527_71586326)

```
// Limit buffer writing
snprintf((char*)&buf, sizeof buf, "  %010.9f W ...
// or 
// Use `%g` to avoid long text
sprintf((char*)&buf, "  %010.9g W ...   
// or 
// Increase buffer size to some worst case - think -DBL_MAX
uint8_t buf[4 * 350] = {0};
```

**True failure?** [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71586326/sprintf-leaves-out-double-data-c/71587418#comment126522418_71587418)

OP only *described* a failure, but did not post the code that could replicate it.

---

**General help**

Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: Thanks @Tom V that was the problem the GNU RISC-V Cross C Linker was not using the float with nano printf (-u_printf_float)